# Uninstalling Hyper-V on a dual-booted machine?

Tags: linux, windows-8, bootloader, hyper-v

I am on Windows 8.1 (dual booting with Crunchbang) and would like to remove Hyper-V. I have tried unticking Hyper-V under "Turning Windows Feature on/off" as well as typing in the command below with no success:

```
Dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

When shutting down Windows notifies me that it is updating itself and upon restarting it says that the update has failed and that windows is restoring the previous state.

I have found [this Microsoft Q&A](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_update/uninstalling-hyper-v-fails/ac3a07bf-fcaf-428d-b183-2c14689adf5f) where the solution was:

> It was as simple as going into disk management, right-clicking my Windows drive, and setting it as active. Now Hyper-V uninstalled correctly!

Doing this scares me a little. Windows and Linux are on the same hard drive. The grub bootloader manages both.

Will I loose access to the bootloader if I make the Windows C drive the active disk?

Is there another way to get rid of HyperV?

**EDIT**

**Partitions on my hard drive**

Not sure if this helps, but anyway... The hard drive has the following partitions:

- System reserved 100 MB (system, primary)
- C: (boot, page file, crash dump, primary)
- ext4 (active, primary)

**Health check**

As per @DanielB 's comment, I ran `Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth` which returned:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: `dism` can also do a health check. Use it to see if your system is OK.

Comment: Please give details about your disks and partitions and whether you are using MBR or GPT. Note that multiple active partitions can exist, and the BIOS will boot the first one it finds.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. I'm not sure which one I'm using though believe that it is MBR. How would I find out about this?

Comment: @DanielB, thanks for the hint. I'll read up on `dism`

Comment: Is Windows 8.1 currently using a Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter as its Ethernet connection?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: This is dual-boot, not a virtual machine.

Comment: I think you had better be prepared for the worse, which is replacing GRUB by the Windows bootloader, boot directly into Windows, uninstall Hyper-V, reinstate GRUB. Prepare your boot&repair CDs for that scenario before experimenting, and perhaps take a backup image of the entire disk. Or you can choose to leave Hyper-V in place, as it is not really a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doing this scares me a little. Windows and Linux are on the same hard
>   drive. The grub bootloader manages both.
>
> Will I loose access to the bootloader if I make the Windows C drive
>   the active disk?

Marking partition as active [flips one byte in MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_flag):

> status / physical drive (bit 7 set: active / bootable, old MBRs only
>   accept 80h), 00h: inactive, 01h–7Fh: invalid)
>
> Originally, status values other than 00h and 80h were invalid, but
>   modern MBRs treat bit 7 as active flag and use this entry to store the
>   physical boot unit.

This flag is used by the old style bootloaders and most modern boot managers ignore it. But there is reports that [GRUB will fail to boot if you mark Windows partition as active](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/457528-GRUB-Loader-will-not-run-if-Windows-is-set-as-the-active-partition). So proceed with caution. It could be a good idea to download [GParted livecd](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) beforehand so you can boot it and mark your Linux partition as active if anything goes wrong.

> Are there any differences between MBR and GPT in this regards, as per
>   @harrymc's comment to the question?

MBR and GPT are different beasts, GPT does have a `Legacy BIOS bootable` flag, but it's not the same. There probably wouldn't be an option in disk management to set `Active` flag from Windows if you're using GPT. And it will mean that you'd have to try something else to get rid of Hyper-V.

To check if your disk uses GPT in Windows:

1. Start `diskpart` from command line
2. Type: `list disk`

   ```
   DISKPART> list disk

   Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
   --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
   Disk 0    Online          698 GB      0 B
   ```

If the `Gpt` is blank (as in example), you're using MBR.

Moreover,  @harrymc states that:

> multiple active partitions can exist, and the BIOS will boot the first
>   one it finds

And that's not completely true. While one can edit partition table to have more than one active partition in MBR scheme, this will [wreak havoc](https://www.google.com/?q=multiple+active+partitions+error).

> So just to be sure, if I change the windows partition to active, and
>   the computer doesn't start up anymore, GParted would allow me to
>   change the active partition back to what it was, right?

Yes. This is how to [set partition as active using GParted](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-manage-partition-flags):

1. Select a partition. In your case it will be your `ext4` partition.
2. Choose: Partition → Manage Flags. The application opens a Manage flags on `/path-to-partition` dialog.

   - Enable `Boot` flag

To enable a flag, select the check box beside the flag. The application writes the enabled flag to the partition and refreshes the Manage flags on `/path-to-partition` dialog.

That should be enough.

Being able to boot Windows\Linux after active partition change is also depends on how your GRUB is configured: are you using Windows bootloader to boot Linux, or are you're booting Windows from GRUB directly?

I suppose it the last one, because otherwise you probably wouldn't be able to boot Windows without it being on active partition. In this case I think that it's pretty safe to mark Windows partition as active, because [GRUB doesn't depends on boot flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23560/what-is-the-bootable-flag-option-when-installing-a-distro) and those reports are for the legacy GRUB ([Crunchbag uses GRUB2](http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/howto/restore_grub2_with_chroot)).

Comment: So just to be sure, if I change the windows partition to active, and the computer doesn't start up anymore, GParted would allow me to change the active partition back to what it was, right? Are there any differences between MBR and GPT in this regards, as per @harrymc's comment to the question? Cheers!

Comment: @pandita See update, hope this will answer your questions.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I will give it a go tomorrow and will let you know if it worked.

Comment: Apologies, this took a bit longer. I ran diskpart and confirmed that I'm using MBR. My Windows started from GRUB. I marked the Windows partition as active while having a gparted stick ready (and still being a bit nervous). However it all went well and I could indeed remove Hyper-V after this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @pandita Good to hear that, glad to be of help :).